# Is it safe to rely on text messages as a means on authentication?

Tags: authentication, mobile, sms

Many websites, including banks, use text messages as their primary or secondary means of authentication. In theory, it sounds like a perfect method unless the user loses their phone or has it infected with a virus.

However, are there any known attacks on text messages that don't rely on access to the actual phone? Is it perfectly safe to rely on text messages as an authentication method?

Comment: Are you referring to two factor authentication?  This is where you log in with a password then they send you a random code.  You then use that code as a second part of the authentication.

Comment: 'safe' is a subjective term. If you are referring to 'two-factor' authentication, then yes in general terms it is 'safer' to use a sms's passcode in addition to a typical password over just using the traditionally password. However, it is not full-proof: http://www.buzzfeed.com/charliewarzel/why-two-factor-authentication-wont-stop-our-security-nightma

Comment: There is no perfect system/method. Text message is just an alternative way to authenticate the user. Bank rely on text message as an authentication method but it doesn't soley rely just on the message. That's why there's 2FA login. It's making the system harder to crack which deters any hackers from wasting their time to try cracking the authentication system. Though the user might lose their phone, however the hacker still need time to know their password to login. It's the user responsibility to change/disable his/her password upon losing sensitive data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion SMS messages for two factor authentication is not a secure design decision compared to other alternatives.

SMS messages are vulnerable to a number of scenarios:

- Malware on the smartphone, the [vast majority of users](https://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/anduser-soups12.pdf) don't check permissions so it's reasonable to assume malware creators could quite easily access SMS. This is especially a problem if the attack against the password originated from the phone too (such as via a phishing app).
- GSM can [potentially be compromised](http://hackaday.com/2013/10/22/cracking-gsm-with-rtl-sdr-for-thirty-dollars/)

An alternative which is superior in pretty much every way is [TOTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm), where basically the user encrypts the time rather than the service having to send something to the user. This way absolutely no communication needs to be made with the 2FA device, and can effectively be used offline.

[Google Authenticator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator) is one popular implementation.

Comment: There's one significant way in which it is inferior: you have to deploy something to your customer base. That is non-trivial for a large organisation, and skews the risk analysis. (To be fair, my own bank deploys something to me, and I'm glad they do, but other banks may make a different decision.)

Comment: Many non-google services are compatible with Google Authenticator, Amazon Web Services for example. But obviously the other issue is if users don't have a smart phone then you need a physical token.

Answer (score 1):

SMS isn't a secure means of authenticating, but it is more secure than nothing.  The point of a second factor is to require more of an attacker before they can gain access.  The idea is that, hopefully, the time it takes to compromise the second factor will buy enough time to detect and fix the compromise of the first.

Thus, it isn't necessary that SMS messages be impossible to compromise, just that it be hard enough to compromise the SMS messages that it is harder for an attacker to get both the password and the SMS together.  There are much better options out there, such as HOTP solutions, but they often require distributing stand alone devices (if you don't want the same phone malware problem).

Security is about balancing risk and cost.  SMS messages are cheap and provide additional security, even if they are not secure on their own.  They raise the bar a little at almost no cost.